# SocketIo.use(function(socket, next)) - Where goes next, how to catch or receive it?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I found example of using socket.IO 1.* width Express 4. Here is a [link](https://github.com/adelura/socket.io-express-solution)

Everyting works perfectly. But there is a code:

```
io.use(function(socket, next) {
try {
    var data = socket.handshake || socket.request;
    if (! data.headers.cookie) {
        return next(new Error('Missing cookie headers'));
    }
    console.log('cookie header ( %s )', JSON.stringify(data.headers.cookie));
    var cookies = cookie.parse(data.headers.cookie);
    console.log('cookies parsed ( %s )', JSON.stringify(cookies));
    if (! cookies[COOKIE_NAME]) {
        return next(new Error('Missing cookie ' + COOKIE_NAME));
    }
    var sid = cookieParser.signedCookie(cookies[COOKIE_NAME], COOKIE_SECRET);
    if (! sid) {
        return next(new Error('Cookie signature is not valid'));
    }
    console.log('session ID ( %s )', sid);
    data.sid = sid;
    sessionStore.get(sid, function(err, session) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (! session) return next(new Error('session not found'));
        data.session = session;
        next();
    });
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err.stack);
    next(new Error('Internal server error'));
}
});
```

So if there is an error, it passes to `next`. But where goes this next? How to handle this error without try, catch. I mean handle where this next is receiving like in express:

```
// something here
// And this is callback function which accepts next with err
functin(err, anythingHere){
   if err
      throw err;
   else
      // some code here
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It goes to the client.

https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-use-fn

> **Errors passed to middleware callbacks are sent as special `error` packets to clients.**
>
> ```
> io.on('connection', (socket) => {
>   socket.use((packet, next) => {
>     if (packet.doge === true) return next();
>     next(new Error('Not a doge error'));
>   });
> });
> ```

Note that any middlewares following it aren't invoked.

On the client-side you can handle then like so:

```
socket.on('error', function(err){
    // do something with err
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sharing another example for convenience

**Node Version** : 12.13.1
**Express** : 4.xx.x
**Socket IO**: 2.1.1
**Socket IO client**: 2.x.x

```
io.use((socket, next) => {
  if (
    process.env.NODE_ENV == "production" &&
    socket.handshake.headers.origin != undefined &&
    socket.handshake.headers.origin == config.SOCKET_ORIGIN
  ) {
    return next();
  } else {
    // return next();
    return next(new Error("Invalid Origin"));
  }
})
  .use(async (socket, next) => {
    if (socket.handshake.query.token != undefined) {
      const verificationResponse = await hlpr.JWTVerification(
        socket.handshake.query.token
      );

      if (verificationResponse.err != null) {
        next(new Error("Unauthorized"));
      } else {
        return next();
      }
    } else {
      next(new Error("Unauthorized"));
    }
  })
  .use(async (socket, next) => {
    console.log("*****  socket   ******");
    console.log("*****  next   ******");
    console.log("*****  payload Middlewar Check   ******");
    return next();
  })
  .on("connection", socket => {
      console.log("User Connected Successfully");
  });
```

Client side code

```
const socket = io.connect('ws://xXx.xXx.x.xXx:xxxx', {
          // resource: 'nodejs',
          transport: true,
          query: {token: "xxxXXXxxXXXXXxxxXXXXxxxxXXXXXXXX"}
        });
        socket.on('connect', () => {
          console.log("*******");
          console.log("Successfull Hand Shake");
          console.log("*******");
        }).on('error', (err) => {
          console.log("************ Error ************")
          console.log("************ Error ************")
          console.log(err)
          console.log("************ Error ************")
             // Show the toaster with the error
             // Try re-connect
             // close the socket connection
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

server side:

```
                        io.use((socket, next) => {
                        const err = new Error("not authorized");
                        err.data = { content: "Please retry later" };
                        next(err)
                    }
```

client side:

```
            socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
            console.log(err instanceof Error); // true
            console.log(err.message); // not authorized
            console.log(err.data); // { content: "Please retry later" }
        });
```

This works, I used.

Answer (score 0):

Server side:

```js
io.use(async (socket, next) => {
  if (!isValidReq) {
    next(new Error("Not valid request"));
  }
});
```

Client side:

```js
socket.on('connect_error', (error) => {
  console.log("Connection error:", error);
});
```